# Confused with php namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces

I've got the following structure in my app:

```
|
|----user folder
|        |
|        |-----Member.php
|        | 
|        |---- tests Folder
|                  |
|                  |-----Member.php
```

Here is my `Member.php` in user folder:

```
<?php

namespace user;

class Member
{
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $cell;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function getCell()
    {
        return $this->cell;
    }

    public function setCell($cell)
    {
        $this->cell = $cell;
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

And here is my Member.php in tests folder:

```
<?php
/*
 * Member class getters and setters tests
 */
namespace user;
use user;

$member = new Member();
$member->setFirstName("Javad");
if($member->getFirstName() == "Javad")
    echo "Test code 1 passed";
else
    echo "Test code 1 failed";

$member = new Member();
$member->setLastName("Akbari");
if($member->getLastName() == "Akbari")
    echo "Test code 2 passed";
else
    echo "Test code 2 failed";

$member = new Member();
$member->setEmail("j2omrani@gmail.com");
if($member->getEmail() == "j2omrani@gmail.com")
    echo "Test code 3 passed";
else
    echo "Test code 3 failed";

$member = new Member();
$member->setPassword("123456");
if($member->getPassword() == "123456")
    echo "Test code 4 passed";
else
    echo "Test code 4 failed";

$member = new Member();
$member->setCell("09121234567");
if($member->getCell() == "09121234567")
    echo "Test code 5 passed";
else
    echo "Test code 5 failed";
```

When I want to create an Object it throws exception and says:

```
Fatal error: Class 'user\Member' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto24\user\tests\Member.php on line 8
```

My question is how can I call the Member Object in the tests folder files using namespaces?

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)? -- `use user\Member;`

Comment: @Orbling, I've tried this but it gives the same error.

Comment: Could you try removing the namespace declaration from the test/member file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You cannot import a namespace (`import user`). You need to import concrete classes instead (`use user\Member`)
2. There is no need of importing `Member`, since it’s in the same namespace
3. `use` statement does not include files. You must consider some kind of autoloading. Consider [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) and/or [Composer](http://getcomposer.org)

To solve your problem *ad hoc*, use include:

```
include '../Member.php';
```

Comment: Better answer than mine, which I have therefore removed.

Comment: now it says Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto24\user\Member.php on line 19

Comment: That's a problem with your code. You haven't shown us line 19!

Comment: Could you post full file contents somewhere? There is probably a circular reference somewhere in there

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the namespace and the class name: `use user\Member;`

**Member.php:**

```
namespace user;
class Member
{
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $email;
    private $password;
    private $cell;
    //and some other stuff
}
```

**Member.php in tests folder:**

```
namespace user\tests\user;
use user\Member;

$member = new Member();
```

I'm presuming you also need to add the following to `Member.php` in tests folder if you haven't:

```
include '../Member.php';
```

Alternatively you could also use an autoloader to load classes/namespaces on the fly.

PHP Autoloading classes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: it doesn't work,could you provide me code so to understand clearly?